# Bad request from Blazor using Signalr after deployment on IIS

Tags: signalr, blazor

I have implemented a Blazor application with Signalr which works fine locally, but when I deploy it to a server with IIS it throws:

> blazor.server.js:15 [2021-03-11T15:35:28.868Z] Error: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).
> at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.NegotiateAsync(Uri url, HttpClient httpClient, ILogger logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

When I compare what Is happening locally with what is happening on the server it looks like it is this request that fails

> [2021-03-11T15:54:20.865Z] Information: WebSocket connected to wss://localhost:44312/_blazor?id=VQLOPgZDJ-bXAb1CqhG1Vw.

I'd highly appreciate some help? If you need more information, let me know. I'd be glad to provide it for you.

Comment: What version IIS are you running?

Comment: @mxmissile version 10

Comment: Have you added the WebSocket protocol to your IIS install?

Comment: no, I have not. interesting.

Comment: Try adding it and see if that eliminates the exception.

Comment: sure will. thanks.

Comment: What flavor of Blazor ? Could you show the HubConnectionBuilder's code.

Comment: @enet I created a follow up question. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66596320/blazor-application-with-signalr-server-side-flavour-returns-bad-request-after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the Websocket protocol is enabled in your IIS install. Do this via Roles and Features in Server Manager. [Official documentation is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-websocket-protocol-support).

Comment: This is truly the correct answer to get rid of the web socket connection error. Unfortunately I still get a bad request response, so I created a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66596320/blazor-application-with-signalr-server-side-flavour-returns-bad-request-after