# Blazor application with Signalr (server side flavour) returns Bad Request after deployment to IIS

Tags: signalr, blazor

I have implemented a Blazor application with Signalr (server side flavour) which works fine locally, but when I deploy it to a server with IIS it throws:

> 2021-03-12 08:41:44.7882|100|WARN|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteRenderer|Unhandled exception rendering component: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request). System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).

Here's the configuration code in Startup.cs:

```
            var url = applicationRoot + "/messagehub";
            logger.LogInformation("Message hub url: " + url);

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapHub<MessageHub>(url);
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
```

and here's the HubConnectionBuilder's code:

```
            Uri url = navigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri(linksSettings.ApplicationRoot + "/messagehub");
            logger.LogInformation("Message hub url: " + url);
            hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl(url)
                .Build();
```

One thing I've noticed is that if I navigate to `https://localhost:55514/messagehub` I get

> Connection ID required

but when I navigate to `https://my-apps.com/sub-app/messagehub` I get

> Sorry, nothing here

which comes from the file `App.razor`

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData"></RouteView>
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <p>Sorry, nothing here</p>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

I don't know if this is because the hub never was instantiated properly or if there's a routing problem.

As you can see I have different application roots locally and on server. Maybe this has something to do with the problem?

Please help!

Comment: I cannot replicate this, what version of .NET is this project?  Does deploying a new unmodified app work, using the built in template? And can you post a bare `MessageHub`?

Comment: tagetframework=dotnetcoreapp3.1

thanks for your help @mxmissile. are you able to get it to work if you configure the hub on https://localhost:5000/foo/messagehub (instead of https://localhost:5000/messagehub)? I just want to know if not having the hub in the root is generating the problem.

what do you mean by "can you post a bare MessageHub?

Comment: I was testing with .NET 5, let me spin up a 3.1 version. Where is MessageHub coming from referenced in this line: `endpoints.MapHub<MessageHub>(url);`?

Comment: Is 'sub-app' set as an Web Application in IIS?

Comment: endpoints.MapHub<MessageHub>(url) Is stated in the Configuration method of the Startup class. And yes, sub-app is a separate web application in IIS.